# Passing Errors from Collection Type Field, Symfony, Twig

Tags: php, error-handling, twig, symfony, symfony-forms

for one of my projects i am working with CollectionType field in symfony 3 and is currently struggling to return errors to my web page in case there are some in the embedded form.

Here is my Form

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;
use AppBundle\Form\SubscriberAddressType;

class SubscriberDetailsType extends AbstractType {
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array                $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

        $builder
            ->add('firstname', TextType::class, [
                'label' => false,
                'required' => true,
                'error_bubbling' => true,
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => 'First Name',
                    'class' => 'form-control'
                    ]])
            ->add('lastname', TextType::class, [
                'label' => false,
                'required' => true,
                'error_bubbling' => true,
                'attr' => array(
                    'placeholder' => 'Last Name',
                    'class' => 'form-control'
                )])
            ->add('emailaddress', EmailType::class, [
                'label' => false,
                'required' => true,
                'error_bubbling' => true,
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => 'Email Address',
                    'pattern'     => '.{2,}',//minlength
                    'class' => 'form-control'
                    ]])
            ->add('subscriberaddress', CollectionType::class, ['entry_type' => SubscriberAddressType::class])
            ->add('submit', SubmitType::class, [
                'label' => 'Sign Up',
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'smoothScroll btn btn-danger sb-button'
                    ]
        ])
             ;
    }

    /**
    * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
    */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(['data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\SubscriberDetails']);
    }
    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName() {
        return 'subscriberdetails';
    }
}
```

Here is my sub-form:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;

class SubscriberAddressType extends AbstractType {
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array                $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

        $builder
            ->add('address1', TextType::class, [
                'label' => false,
                'required' => true,
                'error_bubbling' => true,
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => 'Address 1',
                    'class' => 'form-control'
                    ]])
            ->add('city', TextType::class, [
                'label' => false,
                'required' => true,
                'error_bubbling' => true,
                'attr' => array(
                    'placeholder' => 'City',
                    'class' => 'form-control'
                )])
             ;
    }

    /**
    * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
    */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(['data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\SubscriberAddress']);
    }
    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName() {
        return 'subscriber';
    }
}
```

This is my twig file

```
{% extends "base.html.twig" %}

{% block body %}

    {{ form_start(form, {'attr': {'novalidate': 'novalidate'}}) }}
        <div class="form-group ">
            {{ form_label(form.firstname) }}
            {{ form_widget(form.firstname) }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group ">
            {{ form_label(form.lastname) }}
            {{ form_widget(form.lastname) }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group ">
            {{ form_label(form.emailaddress) }}
            {{ form_widget(form.emailaddress) }}
        </div>  
        <div class="form-group ">
            {% for field in form.subscriberaddress %}
                {{ form_label(field.address1) }}
                {{ form_widget(field.address1) }}
            {% endfor %}      
        <div>
        <div class="form-group ">        
            {% for field in form.subscriberaddress %}
                {{ form_label(field.city) }}
                {{ form_widget(field.city) }}
            {% endfor %}           
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {{ form_row(form.submit, { 'label': 'SEND MESSAGE' }) }}
        </div>

    {{ form_end(form) }}

    {{ form_errors(form) }}
    {% for field in form.subscriberaddress %}
        {{ form_errors(field.address1) }}
        {{ form_errors(field.city) }}
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

I've tried all possible combinations with and without error_bubbling however i still get to see only errors, related to field in the primary form, not the embedded one.

Any assistance will be highly appreciated